# Is it possible to change expression blend keyboard shortcut

Tags: microsoft-expression

I'm using Microsoft Expression Blend 3. I need to change mouse wheel zoom command to up down scroll.

How to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Tools > Options > Artboard**

Change "Mouse Wheel > Zoom by using" to "Ctrl + Mouse wheel" or "Alt + Mouse wheel".